# Using jQuery, how can I highlight all new and existing occurrences of a word as the user types?

Tags: jquery, highlight, typing, keyup

I'm building a simple note-taking tool where certain keywords will automatically highlight as the user types so that they can easily find them later.

I've created a `keyup()` function that listens to a text area and captures the existing content, but I'm unsure how to highlight **all** new and existing occurrences of a word (or array of words).

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/r18v7wpz/44/

```
$("#txt").keyup(function() {
    var keyword = "test";

  var txt = $(this).val();
  $("#page").text(txt);

  var pos = $("#page").text().search(keyword);
    var pageTxt = $("#page").text();

    if(pos >= 0) { 
    pageTxt.substr(pos, keyword.length).replace('<span class="highlight">' + keyword + '</span>');
    console.log("Ran!");
  }
});
```

This only seems to be capturing the first occurrence of the word, albeit still not highlighting like it should. If it's a partial match, the entire word should be highlighted (e.g. "testing" should also highlight for the keyword "test").

A stretch goal would be to define an array of multiple keywords and/or phrases, each of which will be highlighted appropriately, ideally in a different color.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `/test/g` instead of `.replace()`

Here is a sample which works for your case:

```js
$("#txt").keyup(function() {
  var txt = $(this).val();
  var keyword = "test";
  if (txt.indexOf(keyword) > -1){
    $("#page").html(txt.replace(/test/g,'<span class="highlight">' + keyword + '</span>'));
  }
  else {
    $("#page").html(txt);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif !important;
}
textarea {
  padding: 12x;
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 1.4em;
}
.highlight {
  color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="txt" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<div id="page"></div>
```

Comment: This is wonderful. I'm not familiar with /test/g, so I'll read up on why that works. Do you have any recommendations for adapting this to highlight partial matches as well? So words like "testing" would highlight in their entirety since they match the partial "test".

Comment: @Jon Glad to be a help. Yes, you can use /anykeyword/g to find and replace all the occurrences of whatever is between the slashes. I will look into this question as well. See if I can find a solution for it.